# '-alias' is not organized as an internal or external terminal command

Tags: firebase, flutter, alias, keytool, flutter-android

I'm trying to connect the firebase with my flutter project by getting the SHA1 and SHA265, I checked that the keytool is added to the path, but it shows me '-alias' is not organized as an internal or external command. What should I do

Comment: check the path variable, make sure the path to the executable is updated, else try running the package with absolute path

Comment: I did everything is well, the problem is just with '-alias'

Comment: Try with -h or —help and check out the options available , alias might be missing